# weighted stdev calculation in R vs. formula

Tags: r, statistical-significance, variance

I am looking at the formula for weighted variance here

http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/ch2/weightsd.pdf

vs. the wtd.var()

Here is some sample code. Why don't the weighted vars tie?

```
library(Hmisc)
x = c(3,55,5)
w =c(1,10,1)
wtd.var(x, w, normwt = TRUE)

sum(w*(x-mean(x))^2)/((2*sum(w))/3)
```

why don't they tie?

using getAnywhere("wtd.var")

```
function (x, weights = NULL, normwt = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE, method = c("unbiased", 
    "ML")) 
{
    method <- match.arg(method)
    if (!length(weights)) {
        if (na.rm) 
            x <- x[!is.na(x)]
        return(var(x))
    }
    if (na.rm) {
        s <- !is.na(x + weights)
        x <- x[s]
        weights <- weights[s]
    }
    if (normwt) 
        weights <- weights * length(x)/sum(weights)
    as.numeric(stats::cov.wt(cbind(x), weights, method = method)$cov)
}
```

my question is

I's like to reproduce what is happening with

```
x = c(1,2,34)
w = c(200000,.333,.333)
wtd.var(x,w, normwt = TRUE)
```

Looking at the source code I think it is doing:

```
center = colSums(w*x)
x = as.matrix(x)
x <- sqrt(w) * sweep(x, 2, center, check.margin = FALSE)
crossprod(x)/(1 -  sum(w^2))
```

but it does not tie out

Comment: you can examine the code of `wtd.var`  by just typing its name at the console (it's only ~20 lines); then you can see what it does (also see the help which gives a little context, though ti would be good if it had more). The relevant code is right near the end of the function. The pdf you link to actually gives *a* formula for weighted standard deviation; it's not (as it implies) the only formula (by calling it "the" formula). If you want to reproduce the formula in the pdf you can easily write that as a function; it would be a minor modification of the code you wrote above.

Comment: Thanks Glen. I am trying to tie to the cov.wt calculation by reproducing the source code